# mockito fmwk to test java method which uses URL connection to ping external system

Tags: spring-boot, mockito

I'm trying to use mockito fwk for some of the methods I defined to checkConnection and post any document to an API.  Since I'm new to mockito, I'm little confused what and how should I plan my test

I just tried the basics of mockito using assertEquals, but I wanted to know how to mock my scenario better.  In the classes below, class A uses the HTTPSUrlConnection and checks only the connection is successful or not, in class B, its method using the Class A connection object, it tries to send a document to an API.  Now, how do i mock this scenario.

```
class A{

public void checkConnection(){

 HttpsURLConnection con = null;

          URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(endPoint);  //endpoint gets the value from properties file at runtime
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        }
        try {
            con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        String userpass = userName + ":" + password; //gets the value from properties file at runtime
        String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(userpass.getBytes()));
        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        try {
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        }
    }
}






   class B{

     public String send(){

            String responseBody = null;
            SenderResponse senderResponse = null;


            try {
                Resource r = new ClassPathResource("xslt.xsl");
                File f = null;
                f = new File(r.getURL().getPath());
                Source xs = new StreamSource(f);

                Resource r1 = new ClassPathResource("input.xml");
                File f1 = null;
                f1 = new File(r1.getURL().getPath());
                Source xml = new StreamSource(f1)

                TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                tf.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);

                Transformer trans = tf.newTransformer(xs);

                StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
                Result res = new StreamResult(stringWriter);


                trans.transform(xml, res);
                String result = stringWriter.toString();

                OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
                writer.write(result);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();

                if (HttpStatus.OK.value() == con.getResponseCode()) {
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                    String inputLine;
                    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(inputLine);
                    }
                    responseBody = response.toString();
                } else {

                }



        } catch (TransformerFactoryConfigurationError | TransformerException e) {

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {

        } catch (SAXException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
        catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return responseBody;

    }
 }
```

I just want to use the existing methods defined in both these classes rather writing mock codes